# Error while deploying Next.js app on Namecheap shared hosting

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, shared-hosting, namecheap

I have Next.js app created with typescript and I don't want to upload a static build.

I have use the Setup Node.js feature and created a node app that points to my project folder.
The version I select in this Node app was 14.2.0 and type Production

Version of node on My system is 18

My app doesn't show up on my domain.
If I try to run `npm start` command from Cpanel's Terminal I get following error

```
error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: wasm memory
at internal/deps/cjs-module-lexer/dist/lexer.js:1:33593
at async initCJSParse (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:72:5)
at async Loader.commonjsStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:185:18)
at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:67:21)
```

Namecheap support asked me to try few things and one of them was to check on different node versions. However the highest version on Shared hosting is 14.2.0

I don't want to reduce the version on my system then create an app on that.

Can you please assist, is this issue related to versions and will I have to reduce my system' version or is there any other solution to fix this issue